# production.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Data missing in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project in Laravel-5.8. I have this in my model:

Model:

```
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'email',
              'hire_date',
              'first_name',
              'other_name',
              'last_name',
              'date_of_birth',
          ];

protected $dates = [
    'date_of_birth',
    'hire_date',
];

public function setDateOfBirthAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['date_of_birth'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
}

public function setHireDateAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['hire_date'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
}
```

Then this is my controller.

Controller:

```
$arr = [
   'first_name'                => $request->first_name,
   'last_name'                 => $request->last_name,
   'hire_date'                 => $request->hire_date,
   'date_of_birth'             => $request->date_of_birth,
   'other_name'                => $request->other_name,
];

 $employee = HrEmployee::create($arr);
```

I use JQuery datepicker:

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    $('.birthDate').datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      maxDate: -1,
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      duration: 'fast',

    });

  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"> Date of Birth:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" readonly autocomplete="off" name="date_of_birth" value="{{ old(" date_of_birth} ") }}" class="form-control birthDate">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
</div>
```

When I submitted the form, I got this error:

```
[2021-02-12 12:50:07] production.ERROR: InvalidArgumentException: Data missing in /var/www/html/peopleedgeapp/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:623
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php(645): Carbon\Carbon::rawCreateFromFormat('d-m-Y', NULL, NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/myapp/app/Models/Hr/HrEmployee.php(156): Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(615): App\Models\Hr\HrEmployee->setDateOfBirthAttribute(NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(569): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->setMutatedAttributeValue('date_of_birth', NULL)
#4 /var/www/html/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(329): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->setAttribute('date_of_birth', NULL)
```

Where did I get it wrong? The same error occur for hire_date.

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say what's exactly wrong but for sure there is a problem here:

```
value="{{ old(" date_of_birth} ") }}"
```

It should be rather:

```
value="{{ old('date_of_birth') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all set attribute methods are not used for guarded fields.
They have completely different perpouse.

Secondary, according to your error log somehow your setters were triggered with NULL passing instead of parameters, where parameters are required which is also wrong.

So where your setters triggered that is the question I think.